# Probability of birthdays landing on the same day of the week

Tags: probability

1. What is the chance that from a group of 8 people, two people were
   born on Friday?
2. What is the chance that none of them was born on Friday?

Comment: Surely you must have some idea here.  Can you, say, provide a list of possible birthdays (by day of week) such that no two of your $8$ share a day?

Comment: There must be a day, that two shara it.

Comment: You've got part 1 right.  Do you have any ideas for part 2?

Comment: Hint : What is the chance that a fixed person is not born on Friday ? And what the chance that two fixed persons both are not born on Friday ? You can continue.

Comment: For part 2, is it that the chance of no birthday on Friday is 6^8, out of all 7^8 chances ?

Comment: @krolb Yes, you got it!

Comment: Ok, and for the 1st one, is it the opposite of the chance that 6 people were born on one of 6 days, besides of Friday, out of all, so it’s  1-(6^6/7^8) ?